# Confused as to how .next() works in Java iterators without the use of a for-loop

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I created a list of strings in Java and want to iterate through the elements (animal names) that I added using the iterator class. I was wondering why manually typing it.next() in the following code does not print out the animals one-by-one and just prints out the first animal "Dog".

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> animals = new LinkedList<>();

        animals.add("Dog");
        animals.add("Cat");
        animals.add("Fox");
        animals.add("Rabbit");

        Iterator<String> it = animals.iterator();
        String animal1 = it.next();

        System.out.println(animal1);
        it.next();
        System.out.println(animal1);
        it.next()
        System.out.println(animal1);

}
```

The output I get is:

```
Dog
Dog
Dog
```

Why does it not print all the animals line by line? like this:

```
Dog 
Cat
Fox
Rabbit
```

Comment: Basically, it's an internal pointer which references the "next" element in the sequence

Answer (score 2):

Because you're only assigning the result of `it.next()` to `animal1` for the first call.

This will give you the behavior you expect:

```
String animal1 = it.next();
System.out.println(animal1);

animal1 = it.next();
System.out.println(animal1);

animal1 = it.next()
System.out.println(animal1);
```

Comment: Im assuming this has to do with how memory management works in Java? for example, assuming all the code above was Python, my method would work?